# Issues adding a dataset in a package: not an exported object

Tags: r, database, package

Im bulding a package (rohproc) and adding some data for examples. Im using roxygen2 to build the documentation. I storage the data in `rohproc/data/HGDP_hom.rda`. Also in `/scripts/` I added a data.R file with the following:

```
#' ROH in the Human Genome Diversity Panel.
#'
#' This dataset contains the PLINKs .hom file obtained using Human Genome Diversity Panel.
#' PLINKs parameters were set to:
#' homozyg-window-snp 30.
#' homozyg-window-het 1.
#' homozyg-snp 30.
#' homozyg-kb 300.
#' homozyg-density 30.
#' @format ## HGDP_hom
#' A data frame with 612139 rows and 13 variables:
#' \describe{
#'   \item{IID}{individual id}
#'   \item{FID}{family id}
#'   \item{PHE}{Phenotype not present}
#'   \item{CHR}{Chromosome number}
#'   \item{SNP1}{rs of the SNP in starting possition}
#'   \item{SNP2}{rs of the SNP in ending possition}
#'   \item{POS1}{starting of the ROH}
#'   \item{POS2}{ending of the ROH}
#'   \item{KB}{ROH length in KB}
#'   \item{NSNP}{Number of SNP present in the ROH}
#'   \item{DENSITY}{Densito of SNP}
#'   \item{PHOM}{}
#'   \item{PHET}{}
#' }
#' @source \url{https://cephb.fr/en/hgdp_panel.php}
"HGDP_hom"
```

Then, in the funtion script I use:

```
#############################
#' ROH variables
#'
#'This script extracts various valuable variables from a PLINK home file, including:
#'The total sum of ROH (Runs of Homozygosity) greater than or equal to 1.5Mb. (Sum_long).
#'The count of ROH greater than or equal to 1.5Mb (N_long).
#'The total sum of ROH less than 1.5Mb (Sum_short).
#'The count of ROH less than 1.5Mb (N_short).
#'The total sum of ROH for different size categories (0.3MB≤ROH<0.5, 0.5≤ROH<1, 1≤ROH<2, 2≤ROH4, 4≤ROH<8, ROH≥8MB).
#'The genomic inbreeding coefficient, also known as Froh.
#'The homozygosity outside of ROH, referred to as Foutroh.
#' @param data A .hom file obtained using --homozyg flag in PLINK.
#' @return A data frame with the variable previously described.
#' @export
#' @examples
#' # Obtaining basic ROH variables:
#' roh_summ_id(HGDP_hom)
#'
```

When I try to `roxygenise()` I get the following error:

```
ℹ Loading rohproc
Error: 'HGDP_hom' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rohproc'
```

Can you help me solve it?

Comment: Where did you put this data.R file? Did you rebuild the documentation after making the change? Is your package on github or somewhere that we can see exactly how everything is laid out?

Comment: I put data.R in package_name/data/.
Yes, I built the documentation after the change.
Yes, is in github: https://github.com/CeballosGene/rohproc
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you saved the data with different names. The `rda` files store the original object names and use those names when loading the data. If I run `load("data/HGDP_hom.rda")` it loads an object called "KGenomes_hom". And since those names don't match it can't find a data set named HGDP_hom. You want to create a variable named "HGDP_hom" and then use `usethis::use_data(HGDP_hom)` to save the file to the data directory with the correct name.

Comment: Thanks!!!! you are right! What a silly mistake!